# Client-side Blazor hosted in Docker fail while IL linking

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, blazor-client-side, docker-build, blazor-webassembly

I tried to build a Docker image from my client-side Blazor app. The app gets served by the ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.

For this purpose I let VS generate the appropriate Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Gtv.Blazor/Server/Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj", "Gtv.Blazor/Server/"]
COPY ["Blazor/Shared/Gtv.Blazor.Shared.csproj", "Gtv.Blazor/Shared/"]
COPY ["Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj", "Gtv.Blazor/Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Gtv.Blazor/Server/Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Gtv.Blazor/Server"
RUN dotnet build "Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Gtv.Blazor.Server.dll"]
```

While building I get an IL linker error:

```
Step 12/21 : RUN dotnet restore "Gtv.Blazor/Server/Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 40fd2064543b
Step 13/21 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 027a267a84ca
Step 14/21 : WORKDIR "/src/Gtv.Blazor/Server"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 20349fa5c602
Step 15/21 : RUN dotnet build "Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
 ---> Running in d1134f6e3d48
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 28.71 ms for /src/Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj.
  Restore completed in 28.69 ms for /src/Gtv.Blazor/Server/Gtv.Blazor.Server.csproj.
  Restore completed in 1.02 ms for /src/Gtv.Blazor/Shared/Gtv.Blazor.Shared.csproj.
  Gtv.Blazor.Shared -> /app/build/Gtv.Blazor.Shared.dll
  Fatal error in Mono IL Linker
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build/3.2.1/targets/Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj/Release/netstandard2.1/Gtv.Blazor.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [/src/Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj]
   ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj/Release/netstandard2.1/Gtv.Blazor.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
     at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Linker.AssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(IMetadataScope scope)
     at Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve(String name)
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromAssemblyStep.Process()
     at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Execute(String[] args, ILogger customLogger)
     at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build/3.2.1/targets/Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : ILLink failed with exit code 134. [/src/Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build/3.2.1/targets/Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : Unhandled exception. Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'obj/Release/netstandard2.1/Gtv.Blazor.Client.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' [/src/Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build/3.2.1/targets/Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : ILLink failed with exit code 134. [/src/Gtv.Blazor/Client/Gtv.Blazor.Client.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue like you. After deleting everything inside docker the issue has been resolved.

***Following docker command has executed:***

```
powershell command: docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)
powershell command: docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
powershell command: docker system prune --all

docker service restart
```

- First command is to To delete all containers including its volumes
  use
- Second command is to delete all the images
- Third command is to Remove all unused containers, volumes, networks, images and build cache

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#extended-description

***Docker file:***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PrintmillManagement/Server/PrintmillManagement.Server.csproj", "PrintmillManagement/Server/"]
COPY ["PrintmillManagement/Client/PrintmillManagement.Client.csproj", "PrintmillManagement/Client/"]
COPY ["PrintmillManagement/Modules/PrintmillManagement.Modules.csproj", "PrintmillManagement/Modules/"]
COPY ["PrintmillManagement/Infrastructure/PrintmillManagement.Infrastructure.csproj", "PrintmillManagement/Infrastructure/"]

RUN dotnet restore "PrintmillManagement/Server/PrintmillManagement.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PrintmillManagement/Server"
RUN dotnet build "PrintmillManagement.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PrintmillManagement.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PrintmillManagement.Server.dll"]
```